# how to downgrade mono?

Tags: repository, mono, downgrade

i've been trying to modify the repo for it, but all i managed to get was an HTTP 404 Error. can someone tell me how to downgrade mono using repos or from annother way? thanks in advance

Comment: Seems like an XY problem. Downgrading can be a challenge, and is generally unsupported due to the unpredictable results on your system. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: trying to actually use Steam Desktop Authenticator mod 47, but the latest version of mono seems to not collaborate much. i was trying to install an older version (like 5.0.0) with not much luck.

Comment: Consider asking a question about how to get Steam Desktop Authenticator to work, instead of the much more limited question about how to get older versions of mono to install. Other experts here may know a much simpler answer than tinkering with mono.